# Warnings in log files during execution. Do all nodes work?

Tags: debugging, hadoop, warnings

I've been searching for a solution but got nothing. Maybe somebody here faced such a problem and has some idea.

Basically, I work with hadoop trying to do some mapReduce task. One master node and two slaves. Configuration seems ok, since I can ssh from each node to each. I've set `/etc/hosts` and hadoop's configs, such as: `mapred-site.xml`, `hdfs-site.xml`.

After task execution everything seems alright. There were no errors or warnins, but when I `grep WARN` on log files, there are some entries that worries me.

In `tasktracker-master.log` I've found:

```
2013-06-03 14:14:47,525 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
2013-06-03 14:15:00,680 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: TaskTracker's totalMemoryAllottedForTasks is -1. TaskMemoryManager is disabled.
2013-06-03 14:17:44,352 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
2013-06-03 14:17:59,182 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: TaskTracker's totalMemoryAllottedForTasks is -1. TaskMemoryManager is disabled.
2013-06-03 14:23:49,419 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
2013-06-03 14:23:55,156 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: TaskTracker's totalMemoryAllottedForTasks is -1. TaskMemoryManager is disabled.
2013-06-03 14:27:40,619 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
2013-06-03 14:27:46,382 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: TaskTracker's totalMemoryAllottedForTasks is -1. TaskMemoryManager is disabled.
2013-06-03 14:34:15,498 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
2013-06-03 14:34:22,103 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: TaskTracker's totalMemoryAllottedForTasks is -1. TaskMemoryManager is disabled.
2013-06-03 14:36:38,551 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Unknown job job_201306031434_0002 being deleted.
2013-06-03 14:37:17,724 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Unknown job job_201306031434_0003 being deleted.
2013-06-03 14:59:42,395 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
2013-06-03 14:59:48,158 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: TaskTracker's totalMemoryAllottedForTasks is -1. TaskMemoryManager is disabled.`
```

The same thing is in the `slave1/slave2`:

```
tasktracker-slave1.log:
2013-06-03 14:59:34,439 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
2013-06-03 14:59:45,954 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: TaskTracker's totalMemoryAllottedForTasks is -1. TaskMemoryManager is disabled.
2013-06-03 15:01:29,380 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Unknown job job_201306031459_0001 being deleted.
2013-06-03 15:03:14,848 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Unknown job job_201306031459_0003 being deleted.

tasktracker-slave2.log:
2013-06-03 14:59:37,642 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
2013-06-03 14:59:45,805 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: TaskTracker's totalMemoryAllottedForTasks is -1. TaskMemoryManager is disabled.
2013-06-03 15:02:29,489 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Unknown job job_201306031459_0002 being deleted.
```

Anyone has seen any of these warnings and knows what do they mean?

One more thing, how can I find out if the task was actually executing on all supposed nodes `master, slave1, slave2`? Do these warns mean that `slave1/slave2` were not working?

I hope I've described my problem clearly. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are these warns just after you've restarted the cluster services?

Comment: All services (mapred, dhfs) start just ok. Warns appear in logs during execution of map-reduce task.